# Markdown on Github: how to do italics inside code blocks (triple backticks)

Tags: github, markdown

I know on Github with Markdown, a pair of ``` builds a multiple code block. My question is, how I can make words italics inside this code block?

What I want is just italics words inside a code block. Any functionality other than triple backticks ``` is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To look like this...

```
<div class="footer">
    &copy; 2004 Foo Corporation
</div>
italic
```

Build your own codeblock

`<pre><code>&lt;div class="footer"&gt;
    &amp;copy; 2004 Foo Corporation
&lt;/div&gt;
<i>italic</i></code></pre>`

[image: Example of block with italics]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using multiple code blocks, try **bold and italic Unicode characters**. They are especially useful in environments that don’t include formatting tools.

Example:

```
normal text
```

To avoid tedious copy-pasting, [use a text generator like this](https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/).

Comment: "To avoid tedious copy-pasting..."—unfortunately, this also breaks copying _from_ the rendered document since the italic characters are different codepoints.